# load event for iframe does not fire in IE

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I've created an `iframe` in my page here is it's code:

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.setAttribute('src','');
document.body.appendChild(frame);
if(document.addEventListener){
    frame.addEventListener('load', callback, false);
} else {
    frame.attachEvent('onload', callback);
}

function callback(){
    alert('test');
}
```

It works fine in FF but no thing alerted in IE, why?
Note that I use IE10 in win8

Comment: what's the console output?

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht i found no thing in IE console!

Comment: what does the attachEvent return? true of false? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht IE10 uses **addEventListener** not **attachEvent**

Comment: and what if you changed your check into if(frame.addEventListener) instead of if(document.addEventListener)? Thing is, do you actually get into the block where you add the eventlistener to the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `document.body.appendChild()` to after the `addEventListener()` call

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.setAttribute('src','');
if(frame.addEventListener){
    frame.addEventListener('load', callback, true);
} else {
    frame.attachEvent('onload', callback);
}
document.body.appendChild(frame);

function callback(){
    alert('test');
}
```

Comment: It works, but when the callback function invoked the `frame.contentDocument.body` is _null_, can you tell me why?

Comment: In this revised [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LX8qn/2/), the value of frame.contentDocument.body evaluates to an HTMLBodyElement object in Firefox, Chorme, and IE 10.  It does not appear to be null.